# Grails one-to-many / wrongly deleting all "manys"

Tags: grails, associations, grails-orm, one-to-many

i have the following (simplified) domain classes

```
class Filter {
    String name
    static hasMany = [answers:Answer]
    static belongsTo = [user:User]
}

class User {
    String name
    static hasMany = [answers:Answer, filters:Filter]
}

class Answer {
    String text
}
```

Then i add answers to the user which is working perfectly. The problem occurs when i delete 1 answer of a user:

```
def delete = {
    def answer = Answer.get(params.id)
    def users = User.withCriteria() {
        answers{
            eq("id", answer.id)
        }
    }

    for (user in users)
        user.removeFromAnswers(answer)

    answer.delete(flush:true)
    redirect(action:"index")
}
```

What happens here is that ALL user --> answer associations get deleted.

I only want to delete this 1 answer and of cause all associations the answer is used.

I know this has to do with the missing belongsTo, but i can't use it because a ansswer can either belong to a user or to an filter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `belongsTo` to set them to `nullable`:

```
class Answer {
    String text

    static belongsTo = [user:User, filter:Filter]
    static constraints = {
        user nullable:true
        filter nullable:true
    }
}
```

and then just delete the `Answer` directly in the Controller:

```
def delete = {
    def answer = Answer.get(params.id)
    answer.delete(flush:true)
}
```

GORM will take care of the rest the cascading for you.

Comment: mhhh yes that works... but then it's also possible to have an Answer which has no filter and no user... That's why I tried not to use the belongsTo.

Comment: Well... your answer is actually correct for the question I was asking. I assume what i actually want is a many-to-may relationship with 2 joint tables: 1 for filter-->answers and 1 for user-->answers. GORM was actually doing it for me because I have not specified a belongsTo relationship

Comment: With no `belongsTo` it is still possible to have an `Answer` with no `Filter` and no `User`. You can always add a custom constraint or a beforeInsert/beforeUpdate to prevent this from happening.